# running latex from .bat file fails

Tags: command-line

I am trying to write a .bat file for my Windows machine that removes page numbers and converts the pdf to a png file with `pdfcrop` and `pdftoppm`. The conversion part is not an issue; running latex from the .bat file is what I'm having trouble with. For example if I make a file `mycmd.bat` containing

```
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{%1}'
```

and run `mycmd bbb` on the file `bbb.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

then in the terminal I get

```
C:\Users\<user>\Downloads> mycmd bbb

C:\Users\<user>\Downloads>pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{bbb}'
pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `''.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
<*> '\AtBeginDocument
                     {\pagestyle{empty}}\input{bbb}'
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-C to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

But if I run the command `pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{bbb}'` directly in the terminal then it works fine.

My only guess is that latex has an issue with the percent in `%1` from the .bat file. If this is the issue, how can I fix it? If not, what is going wrong?

Comment: I think you need to put the `%1` in quote marks of some form, like `"%1"` in your .bat file. If not then hopefully someone knows the answer, might be a good question for superuser if you don't get an answer over here

Comment: @JamesT I had tried quotes but no luck. Should've put that in the question

Comment: You need double quotes. Single quotes are not special in Windows Batch (in fact Windows Batch file is very complicated) ■ edit actually maybe not, but the behavior of command-line versus in batch file is also different so not sure

Comment: @user202729 Ah yes that works, thanks! Feel free to post as an answer

Comment: you can post one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user202729 mentioned in the comments, you need to use double quotes around the entire argument of `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{empty}}\input{%1}"
```

Probably Windows-specific.